# xpath - Import div by id

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula

Using importxml/ xpath in Google spreadsheet I can import a html `span` element with a certain id:

```
=importxml("https://stackoverflow.com"; "//span[@id='svnrev']")
```

What is the xpath code to find a `div` with a certain id? I tried:

```
=importxml("https://stackoverflow.com"; "//div[@id='interestingTags']")
=importxml("https://stackoverflow.com"; "//div[@id='interestingTags']/a")
=importxml("https://stackoverflow.com"; "//*[@id='interestingTags']")
```

But I always get an error (import is empty). That's the HTML I'm trying to import:

```
<div id="interestingTags"><a href="/questions/tagged/adwords-script" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;adwords-script&#39;" rel="tag">adwords-script</a> </div>
<span id="svnrev">rev 2017.8.31.26908</span>
```

**Update:** What I want to see as a result is either

```
<a href="/questions/tagged/adwords-script" class="post-tag" title="show questions tagged &#39;adwords-script&#39;" rel="tag">adwords-script</a>
```

... or just: `adwords-script`

Comment: That div id is actually empty, I think.

Comment: No, it contains a link with the text "adwords-script"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved: The div I tried to target was dynamic content that was only shown in this session.

Usually, the code works fine. Here another example that works:

```
=importxml("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp"; "//*[@id='nav_examples']")
```